# Writing an iterator using a templated stack

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

How exactly would one go about writing the end function for a templated class, called Stack, that is implemented using an array to go one beyond the bounds of the array?

This is my current end() function:

```
template<typename T>
StackIterator<T> Stack<T>::end() const
{
    //iterator takes a stack and an item of type <T>
    StackIterator<T> goodBye(*this, items[-1]);
    return goodBye;
}//end end function
```

This current implementation will work for primitive types but throws a 
bad_alloc at memory location (...) when used with strings.

Any ideas on how to make this more versatile?

Answer (score 0):

It should not be `items[-1]`. For an array of size n, it should be `items[n]`. In C++11 you can find `std::end` which can do this job.

Of course, you could just use `std::stack`... but hey.

Edit: Iteration in the plain sense only works on native arrays in one direction. If you wish to reverse iterate over a native array, you must start with the forward `[begin, end)` range and implement reverse iteration from there.

Comment: But this means that I would be iterating from the bottom of the stack upwards, as opposed to going from the top down. And I realize that std::stack could be used but the homework assignment was to create it all from scratch.

Comment: @D1990c: Your implementation should invert that directionality. Arrays go forwards.

Comment: Regardless of which way the array is traversed the same error will occur when attempting to do this when the array has elements at every position